# Angular ng-class classes based on functions evaluation

Tags: angularjs

I want to add two classes on li element based on functions evalution in controller.

I was trying this but it won't work

```
<li ng-repeat="p in projects"
    ng-attr-id="{{p.id}}"
    ng-click="selectProject(p)"
    ng-class="{active:isSelected(p.id), getStatusClass(p.status)}"
    class="list-group-item">
        <span>[[p.name]]<span>
</li>
```

isSelected function returns boolean value, whereas getStatusClass returns name of the css class.

Is there any way to do that in angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use combination of `class` attribute and `ngClass` directive

```
<li class="{{ getStatusClass(p.status) }}" ng-class="{ 'active' : isSelected(p.id) }" ></li>
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!